# How can I translate a CheckboxListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, translate

This is my code:

```
CheckboxListTile (
                  value: agree,
                  title: Text (AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Do you accept the terms and conditions?'),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.agree = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

The error is:

> a non null string must be provided to a text widget

Comment: It means `AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Do you accept the terms and conditions?')` this part returns a null. Find the reason why it does that.

Comment: Have you added "Do you accept the terms and conditions?" in the translation files?

Comment: @mohammadalzabibi Yes i was that the error, thank you :) !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want it to be translated, you have to check your folder: assets > lang

You will see all the translations that are in your project, I have put the following in the English one:

"DoYouAcceptTheTermsAndConditions?": "Do you accept the terms and conditions?",

And in Spanish:

"DoYouAcceptTheTermsAndConditions?": "¿Aceptas los términos y condiciones?",

If you have any questions, you can ask me questions: D

EDIT: My code now it looks like this:

CheckboxListTile (
title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('DoYouAcceptTheTermsAndConditions?'),
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
value: agree,
onChanged: (bool value) {
setState(() {
this.agree = value;
});
},
),

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a fallback text in the Text widget

```
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Do you accept the terms and conditions?' ?? 'Do you accept the terms and conditions?');
```